# Как удалить нужную строку из файла, если в файле есть похожая строка

Tags: linux, sed

В демонах `NetworkManager` хранятся строки, которые начинаются с `ExecStartPre`

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c "if [ -f /etc/resolvconf/run/resolv.conf ]; then ln -nsf /etc/resolvconf/run/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf; else rm -f /etc/resolv.conf; fi"
ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
```

Нужно удалить строку `ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -f /etc/resolv.conf`

Использую команду:

```
sed -i '/ExecStartPre/d' /lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service
```

После выполнения в файле удаляются две строки, а хотелось бы удалить только с `rm -f` и здесь начинаются проблемы ... `sed` не принимает строку в аргументе и находит ошибочный формат, я передаю так:

```
sed -i '/ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -f /etc/resolv.conf/d' /lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service
```

На что в выводе получаю `sed: -e выражение #1, символ 23: неизвестная команда: -` Видимо он принимает параметр команды `-f` за команду. Или ему не нравятся пробелы, не понятно.
Как этого избежать?

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/112834

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Экранируйте же:

```sh
$ sed -i '/ExecStartPre=\/bin\/rm -f \/etc\/resolv\.conf/d' /lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service
```

Comment: аа понял, спасибо большое!